# Stringify JavaScript object Not gives right data

Tags: javascript, json

**I am getting this value**

```
     [ { "name": "sname", "value": "Agency" }, { "name": "pincode", "value": "110031" }, { "name": "add", "value": "Agency IX/6242, 1st Floor, h Mohaa No.1, nehru Gali, Near Sanatan Dh, Gand, " }, { "name": "city", "value": "Delhi" }, { "name": "state", "value": "Delhi" }, { "name": "country", "value": "India" }, { "name": "phone", "value": "9990" }, { "name": "email", "value": "a@gmail.com" }
```

**but I want like the given below**

```
   seller": {"name": "Walter White","pincode": "400005","address": "abc, xyz","city": "Mumbai","state": "Maharashtra","country": "India","phone": "99999999999","email": "walter.white @test.com"},
```

**My code is**

```
   form id="myFormvama" method="POST">
  <label>Seller Name</label><input type="text" name="sname" value=""><br>
   <label>Pincode</label><input type="text" name="pincode" value=""><br>
   <label>Address</label><input type="text" name="add" value=""><br>
   <label>City</label><input type="text" name="city" value=""><br>
   <label>State</label><input type="text" name="state" value=""><br>
   <label>Country</label><input type="text" name="country" value=""><br>
   <label>Phone</label><input type="text" name="phone" value=""><br>
   <label>Email</label><input type="text" name="email" value=""><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Request" id="submit">

  </form>
  <script>
   var formData = JSON.stringify($("#myFormvama").serializeArray());
    document.write(formData); 
   </script>
```

Please anyone suggest me snippet so that I can get the proper value in json.

Comment: `var formData = { name: $("[name=sname]").val(), pincode: $("[name=pincode]").val() ....... }`

Comment: Well...then you'll need to do something different, as [jQuery's `serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) is quite clear that it produces an **array** in that form.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new object using Array#reduce:

```
var formData = JSON.stringify($("#myFormvama").serializeArray());

formData = formData.reduce(function (obj, next) {
  obj.seller[next.name] = next.value;
  return obj;
}, { seller: {} });
```